# How to loop an array of points with delay in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, delay, point

I'm trying to loop trough an array of Points with a delay, but nothing happens and I don't get errors.
Here's an example of what my code looks like:

```
public class Class {    
    private Point[] points;
    private int start, delay;

    public Class() {
        points = new Point[] {
            new Point(1, 1),
            new Point(2, 1),
            new Point(1, 2)
        };
        start = System.nanoTime();
        delay = 500;
    }

    public void update() {
        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - startT) / 1000000;
            if(elapsed > delay) {
                System.out.println("x: " + points[i].x);
                System.out.println("y: " + points[i].y);
                start = System.nanoTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything inside the update function is working except for that `for` loop.

edit:
It's a java Swing application with only 1 thread.

Answer (score 3):

One of your problems is that you're using an if block and not a while loop. An if block just checks once, sees that the condition is false, and skips over it. A while loop will loop until the condition is false.

- For most delays you could use a general purpose Timer object such as a java.util.Timer together with a java.util.TimerTask object.
- for delays in a Swing GUI you would use a javax.swing.Timer
- Other options for general non-Swing computing including using a while loop that contains a `Thread.sleep(...)` call.
- Also look into using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` for non-Swing delays.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your edit:

> edit: It's a java Swing application with only 1 thread.

- Then use a javax.swing.Timer. You can find the tutorial here: [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- And here's the [Swing Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- Also have a look at the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more on Swing development.

If you need more help, then as we've already mentioned, provide more detail in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to use a timer instead. I will posts results as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To sleep for an aproximate amount of time use `Thread.sleep(millis);`
Do not expect accuracy to be more than 30ms.

Comment: I tried to use Thread.Sleep(millis);. I forgot to mention it is a small game with only 1 thread and if i do Thread.Sleep(millis); the whole game pauses. But thanks anyway for your contribute. It was my bad for not mentioning it in the question.

Comment: @BisaZ: this means that you're leaving some important information out of your question. Please update your question with the important details -- is this a Swing GUI? What behavior are you trying to achieve? 1+ to this answer BTW.

Comment: Already updating anda again i'm sorry i'm new to stack overflow. I can't plus one for that same reason.